# Unable to dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, windows-10

I want to dual boot Windows 10 21H1 and Ubuntu 20.04, but when I load Ubuntu to install it, it does not show my partitions correctly. It shows all my partitions values in one place and sometimes it shows a little lock besides it.

I have an SSD and an HDD together and I have disabled bitlock.

This is the picture of the Ubuntu problem I'm referring to:

[image: Screenshot 1]

And these are all my partitions:

[image: Screenshot 2]

What should I do?

Comment: Ubuntu is not installed. Your screenshot in Ubuntu shows a live session of the installation media.  Your installation media is also out-of-date. You should create new bootable installation media. Presumably you want Ubuntu on the last partition of the 1TB drive. Using the same live session, if there is a partition there, delete it, and you can install Ubuntu there. Make sure that you boot the USB consistent with how Windows is already installed, which appears to be UEFI.

Comment: * it shows a little lock beside it* -- Ensure that secure boot and fast startup are turned off.